# Total Variation Mesure according to Jordan Decomposition

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be a signed measure in $(X,\mathcal{A})$. Then how can I show that for $A \in \mathcal{A}$ that:

$$|\mu|(A) = \mu^+(A) + \mu^-(A) = \sup \left \{  \sum_{j=1}^n|\mu(B_j)|: B_j \in \mathcal{A}, B_j  \text{ disjoint and } \cup_{j=1}^n B_j = A \right \}$$

The previous expression is according to the Hahn Decomposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use my notation. $E$ is your $A$ and $E_j$'s are your $B_j$'s.

$\ge$: Observe that for $E\in\mathcal{A}$, $$|\mu|(E)\leq|\mu^+(E)|+|\mu^-(E)|=|\mu|(E)$$
By countable additivity,
$$|\mu|(E)=\sup\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\mu|(E_j):\ldots\right\}\ge\sup\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\mu(E_j)|:\ldots\right\}$$
$\leq$: Apply Hahn decomposition, $|\mu|(E)=|\mu|(E\cap A)+|\mu|(E\cap B)$, where $A$ is $\mu^+$-null and $B$ is $\mu^-$null. Then try to show that $|\mu|(E\cap A)=|\mu(E\cap A)|$ and $|\mu|(E\cap B)=|\mu(E\cap B)|$. Since $E=(E\cap A)\cup(E\cap B)$,
$$|\mu|(E)=|\mu(E\cap A)|+|\mu(E\cap B)|\leq\sup\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\mu(E_j)|:\ldots\right\}$$
Done.

Comment: I am just failing to see the reason for the last $\leq$, why can you say $|\mu|(E)=|\mu(E\cap A)|+|\mu(E\cap B)|\leq\sup\left\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\mu(E_j)|:\ldots\right\}$

Comment: @JohannMartens By definition.

Comment: Got it, since both these $E \cap A$ and $E \cap B$ are subsets of $E$. I just had a little bit of trouble with the notation :)

Comment: @JohannMartens Correct.